# Flexible Container in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm making Container box with Flexible funtion but it doesn't work flexible rate (3:7).
Could you explain why it doesn't work?

Codes are below.

```
body: Container(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Flexible(child: Container(
            color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
            child: Text("Hi, Lynn",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
            ),
          ), flex: 3,),
          Flexible(child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: const MyStatefulWidget()
          ), flex: 7,)
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `Flexible` it still makes children smaller than the flex when there is enough space. I believe you want to use `Expanded`. Try replacing it with that

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Expanded` widget instead of `Flexible`

```
Container(
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
          child: Text("Hi, Lynn", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),),
        ), 
        flex: 3,
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Text("Hi, Lynn",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),)
        ), 
        flex: 7,
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```